# How to subtrate a diferent value in all columns in R

Tags: r

I got this data.frame

```
Data = data.frame(    Time = seq(1,5),
                    v1 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9),
                    v2 = c(0.1, 0.12, 0.41, 0.72, 0.91),
                    v3 = c(0.03, 0.13, 0.62, 0.50, 0.90))
```

but i need to subtrate a certain value in all columns

```
subtrate = data.frame(v1 = 0.1, v2 = 0.3, v3 = 0.5)
```

To get this result:

result =

```
   v1    v2    v3
1 0.0 -0.20 -0.47
2 0.1 -0.18 -0.37
3 0.3  0.11  0.12
4 0.6  0.42  0.00
5 0.8  0.61  0.40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `purrr` you can try:

```
map2_df(Data[-1], subtrate, `-`)
```

**Output**

```
     v1    v2    v3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   0   -0.2  -0.47
2   0.1 -0.18 -0.37
3   0.3  0.11  0.12
4   0.6  0.42  0   
5   0.8  0.61  0.4
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do:

```
library(tidyverse)
Data %>%
  pivot_longer(-Time) %>%
  left_join(subtrate %>% pivot_longer(everything(), values_to = 'minus'), by = 'name') %>%
  mutate(value = value - minus) %>%
  select(-minus) %>%
  pivot_wider()
```

Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
   Time    v1     v2    v3
  <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   0   -0.20  -0.47
2     2   0.1 -0.18  -0.37
3     3   0.3  0.110  0.12
4     4   0.6  0.42   0   
5     5   0.8  0.61   0.4
```

Answer (score 1):

With base R, we can use `mapply`:

```
Data[-1]<-mapply(\(x,y) x - y, Data[-1], subtrate)
Data

  Time  v1    v2    v3
1    1 0.0 -0.20 -0.47
2    2 0.1 -0.18 -0.37
3    3 0.3  0.11  0.12
4    4 0.6  0.42  0.00
5    5 0.8  0.61  0.40
```